# Rails :has_many make sure one is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a installations and versions model and a installation as many versions. With a installation you can create many versions and the user needs to select a version which will be marked as default in the versions database with a boolean datatype.

How can I make sure the user has selected a version from a list of many different versions from within the installation screen. Only one can be selected and then the `default` field of the versions model is changed to 'YES' and all the other versions that belong to the installation is set to 'NO'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a foreign_key `:default_version_id` to the installation model to track the default version instead of using an entire column in the Version class for this purpose. That would make the validation easier too.
Anyway, with the current implementation the validation rule would look something like this:

```
Class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions

  validate :default_version_must_be_selected

  private

  def default_version_must_be_selected
    if versions.collect{|v| v if(v.default == true)}.compact.length != 1
      errors.add(:base, 'one default version is required'
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

By removing the `default` flag from `Version` and adding `default_version_id` to `Installation` the implementation would be more straight forward:

```
Class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions
  belongs_to :default_version, class_name: 'Version'

  validates_presence_of :default_version_id
end
```

I think you'll find that interacting with an installations default version will become a lot easier with this approach. It's just an association.

Comment: Thank you. Can you expand on `:default_version_id` I'd be interested to see what the difference is.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer with more info about how I'd approach the problem